# flash/session not found after migration to 2.3

Tags: playframework-2.0, scala-template

I have such error in scala template:

```
not found: value flash

19        @if(flash.contains("bladLogowania")) { 
20        <p class="error">
21        @flash.get("bladLogowania")
22       </p>}
```

I have read that there is some change but I am not sure how make this work. I still want check this values from template directly. Any ideas?

Comment: There was other problem - I made mistake in build.stb. Now is working even with code given above.

Answer (score 2):

Change your controller code to **request.flash** instead of just **flash**

Answer (score 1):

Changes I made to compile after 2.3 migration where using implicit flash becomes an issue:

**To my Controller class:**

add `import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader;`

change `flash("success", "Logged Out");`

to `request.flash("success", "Logged Out");`

**To my scala.html classes using the implicit flash:**

add `(implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)`

change

```
@if(flash.contains("success")) {
                <p class="success">
                    @flash.get("success")
                </p>
            }
```

to

```
@if(request.flash.data.contains("success")) {
                <p class="success">
                    @request.flash.get("success")
                </p>
            }
```

Note the need to access the map using flash.data.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please read the migration guide to 2.3: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23, specifically the *"Session and Flash implicits"* section

So your code would change to:

```
@if(request2flash.contains("bladLogowania")) { 
  <p class="error">
    @request2flash.get("bladLogowania")
  </p>
}
```

Comment: Urm, why the downvote? I'm literally quoting Play migration docs to 2.3? 

_"The name of these was changed to avoid conflicts where these parameter names might be shadowed by application local variables with the same name. `session` became `request2session`, `flash` became `request2flash`, `lang` became `request2lang`. Any code that invoked these explicitly consequently will break.

It is not recommended that you invoke these implicit methods explicitly,..."_

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but the last statement of your comment should tell you why. request.flash is the recommended way

Comment: In testing, I was unable to use the replacement variables according to the documents and can confirm that request.flash worked instead.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same kind of errors when code for Play 2.3.X.
I found that documentation about migration to 2.3.X is wrong. Digging the Play api doc I found  that you just have to add a import to Http.context.Implicit to acess flash scope like you did before play 2.3.X:

```
@import play.mvc.Http.Context.Implicit
```